# Renaming nested list when some elements are null

Tags: r, purrr

How do I rename a nested list that may or may not have values using `purrr`? I tried `modify_at()` but getting errors if one of the lists is blank

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- 
  list(
    list(
      app = list(id = 123, name = "abc"), 
      tag = list(id = 456, name = "def")
    ),
    list(
      app = list(id = 345, name = "xyz"), 
      tag = list(id = 678, name = "abc")   # <--- works
    # tag = NULL                           # <--- doesn't work

    )
  )
```

I want `app$id` and `app$name` to become `app_id` and `app_name` and ultimately return a data frame

```
| app_id | app_name | tag_id | tag_name |
|--------|----------|--------|----------|
|    123 |      abc |    456 |      def |
|    345 |      xyz |        |          |
```

This example works if both apps have tags but if any of the tags are `null` (switch the comments above), the `modify_at("tag")` step fails

```r
my_list |> 
  map(
    ~.x |> 
      modify_at("app", ~set_names(.x, glue("app_{names(.x)}"))) |> 
      modify_at("tag", ~set_names(.x, glue("tag_{names(.x)}"))) |> 
      as.data.frame() |>   # also why doesn't as_tibble() work here?
      rename_all(str_replace_all, "\\.", "_")
  ) |> 
  list_rbind()
```

Specifically, here:

```r
my_list |> 
  map(
    ~modify_at(.x, "tag",  ~set_names(.x, glue("tag_{names(.x)}")))
  )
# Error in `map()`:
#   ℹ In index: 2.
# Caused by error in `map()`:
#   ℹ In index: 1.
# ℹ With name: tag.
# Caused by error in `set_names()`:
#   ! `x` must be a vector
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/804) on GitHub but still had issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a custom function:

With this function we handle `NULL` elements by replacing them with a list of `NA` elements. We then use `map_vec` to convert the lists into a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_func <- function(list, prefix) {
  if(is.null(list)) {
    list <- list(id = NA, name = NA)
  }
  set_names(list, paste0(prefix, "_", names(list)))
}

my_list |> 
  map(
    ~ list(
      app = my_func(.x$app, "app"),
      tag = my_func(.x$tag, "tag")
    )
  ) |> 
  map_vec(
    ~ bind_cols(.x$app, .x$tag)
  )
```

```
app_id app_name tag_id tag_name
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
1    123 abc         456 def     
2    345 xyz          NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without needing to explicitly rename beforehand.  You just need to row bind the inner lists and then the result and pivot.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_list |>
  map(bind_rows, .id = "element") |>
  bind_rows(.id = "list_id") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = element, 
              values_from = c(id, name),
              names_glue = "{element}_{.value}",
              names_vary = "slowest")

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  list_id app_id app_name tag_id tag_name
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
1 1          123 abc         456 def     
2 2          345 xyz          NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a `purrr` solution, but this can also be done using `rrapply()` (in package `rrapply`):

```
rrapply::rrapply(
  my_list, 
  condition = Negate(is.null),                ## filter NULLs
  how = "bind",                               ## unnest to wide data.frame 
  options = list(coldepth = 2, namesep = "_") ## additional unnesting options
) 
#>   app_id app_name tag_id tag_name
#> 1    123      abc    456      def
#> 2    345      xyz     NA     <NA>
```